# How to fix an error with saving file "index.Rmd" in Blogdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I wanted to help with one question, but was recieved my own.
**Where is a problem?**

I tried to repeat some basics from there: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html

- all instructions were followed and fulfilled;
- **hugo** was downloaded and installed;
- site was launched by `blogdown::serve_site()`.

**It works! But...**

```
Launching the server via the command:
  C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Hugo/0.89.4/hugo.exe server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t hugo-lithium -D -F --navigateToChanged
Serving the directory . at http://localhost:4321
Launched the hugo server in the background (process ID: 1780). To stop it, call blogdown::stop_server() or restart the R session.
```

... look, where is a **message**??? (as you can see [there](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/images/serve-site.png)):

```
 Rendering content/post/2020-12-01-r-rmarkdown/index.Rmd... Done.
```

Ok, I tried to add content to `index.Rmd`:

````
```{r}
summary(Orange)
```
````

And, after saving, we can see this message:

[image]

Again these hellish replacement symbols and (`Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")` didn't help, but this isn't a story about them).

How to fix this problem with `index.Rmd` in `blogdown`?  Maybe someone faced with it?

Very grateful for the help.

---

**And a little addition.**

I deleted and recreated "my website".

This string was displayed...

`Rendering content/post/2020-12-01-r-rmarkdown/index.Rmd... Done.`

... but error is the same ...

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for the future sufferers and thoughtless persons (as I am):

**Guys, we shouldn't touch the "index.Rmd" in the main directory of our site's folder!**

[image]

Am I right?

---

**Some proposals to [Yihui Xie:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie)**

Why "the main index.Rmd" can't have an other name, f.e.:

```
mainIndex;
primaryIndex;
baseIndex;
etc...
```

... and it will be nice, if you add to this file some info, f.e.

```
<!-- If you want to add some new info to your site - come to "content - post - bla-bla - index.Rmd" --> 
<!-- Please don't try to edit the current file --> 
---
site: blogdown:::blogdown_site
---
```

*Or nevertheless someone can add something and save after "index.Rmd"?*

Comment: I've added a comment to this file: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/3d75c35b4c9991c1517924dc11b730cf954637c6 Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @YihuiXie Big thanks! We will see this update in the new version of blogdown package?

Comment: No, existing `index.Rmd` won't be updated (it is read-only, which is why you couldn't save the edit). The change only applies to new sites.