# Force relative paths in knitr::include_graphics()

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I need the output to be portable so all the file paths need to be relative to the root directory of the project not absolute paths. I also need to set the figure size so I can't fall back on markdown and just use  but knitr insists on creating an absolute path in my output. I've tried setting `root.dir` & `base.dir` and `fig.path` in various combinations but I keep getting an absolute path in my output. Setting `root.dir = "/"` does change the path in my output but setting it to "" or "./" still results in an abs path so this is not helping produce a portable output.
My `rmarkdown::render` is being run from the same directory as the Rmd file, the output is to this same directory and the graphics files are in a sub-directory of the one with the notebook. Is the a way I can make knitr just us the paths I give it and not try to transform them in any way?

Issues with knitr & paths seem to be a common problem and there are a lot of stub Q&As out there in search results which often don't satisfactorily resolve the problem, or if they do resolve it the questioner and/or answer seem unclear on why it worked.
I've referred to https://yihui.org/knitr/ & https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ and I still don't have a satisfactory understanding of how to control output paths with knitr could someone help me understand how to control this or point me in the direction of a resource that can?

---

OK so calmed down and I tried to make a reprex, I found some interesting behaviour.
The graphics folder is a symlink to a folder in the parent directory and this works fine if I use as basic html_document output but when I use the revealjs::revealjs_presentation output I get different results in the basics document the img tag contains:

src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD......."

and in the presentation contains:

src="/home/richardjacton/project/graphics_test/example.jpg"

Now this does not work because I need to be able to move the directory containing the presentation and it's assets to somewhere else and have it work once built.

If I go in with inspect element and edit it to src="./graphics/example.jpg" that works.

Also If I make a real directory instead of a symlink to the a directory in the parent then I get src="graphics/example.jpg" in the revealjs output

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "Richard J. Acton"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
# output:
#   html_document:
#     df_print: paged
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    theme: dark 
    highlight: zenburn 
    center: true
    self_contained: false
    reveal_plugins: ["notes"]
    reveal_options:
      slideNumber: true
      previewLinks: true
    fig_caption: true
---

# Example

```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, message=FALSE}
fs::dir_create("../graphics_test/")
download.file("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0hMr5-05bFc/maxresdefault.jpg", "../graphics_test/example.jpg")
fs::link_create("../graphics_test", "graphics")

# fs::dir_create("graphics")
# download.file("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0hMr5-05bFc/maxresdefault.jpg", "graphics/example.jpg")

```

```{r, out.width='80%', echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("graphics/example.jpg")
```
````

In my real case I'm creating a presentation from inside a {targets} project that's also has a {bookdown} project in it that produces a report based on the pipeline. So the presentation lives in a sub-directory so I can exclude it from the bookdown build. I explicitly built the presentation with an rmarkdown::render call as the knit button in the gui wants to try and render the book: `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",envir = new.env())`. Also this is all in a directory mounted to a docker container that's running my RStudio server instance so I have a portable and reproducible working environment for any non-R dependencies of my pipeline.

So this is why I was looking for a resource with a more in depth explanation of what exactly happens when I make a `knitr::include_graphics` call because this is the sort of weird edge case I seem to encounter a lot and get stuck trying to debug. Thanks for the response @YihuiXie I love your work and use it daily - sorry for offering you the opportunity to engage with this particular headache.

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you an answer without you providing a reproducible example because there are too many possibilities and it would be hard for us to guess one by one. `xfun::relative_path()` might help, but again, it's hard to help you before you provide more details.

Comment: @YihuiXie Sorry for bothering, but can you look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058358/how-to-fix-an-error-with-saving-file-index-rmd-in-blogdown

Comment: Have you tried doing this as an RStudio project?  Use `here::here()` to set relative paths.

Comment: @user101089 The trouble is not giving the correct relative path to  `knitr::include_graphics` which I could get with `here` it is how `knitr::include_graphics` or something else in the document build pipeline changes the path I give it in the document that is produced.